# How to gracefully shutdown Spring context startup when JMS server does not connect?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I am using Spring JMS to connect to ActiveMQ, but sometimes the ActiveMQ server may be offline. To make my application stop retrying to connect after some timeout is reached I am using the following:

```
<jms:listener-container factory-id="jmsListenerContainerFactory"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        back-off="jmsBackOff" />

<bean id="jmsBackOff" class="org.springframework.util.backoff.ExponentialBackOff">
    <property name="maxElapsedTime" value="600000"/>
</bean>
```

But the problem is I want the application to die when this timeout is reached, interrupting the Spring context startup process.

I tried creating my own `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and overriding its `stop()` method to throw an exception, but this only kills its own thread, stalling the context startup instead of shutting it down.

Is there any way I can gracefully shutdown Spring context startup at this point? Or, even better, add a hook to be executed when `BackOffExecution#STOP` is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `System.exit(-1)` instead of throwing an exception in the stop method of your DefaultMessageListenerContainer?